# PHP contact form issues

Tags: php, html, post, contact-form

I am having some trouble sending the results from a contact form to an email address. I click submit and my php script is telling me it has been successful...but nothing yet has hit my mail box. Please can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong.

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Contact - James Novis Tuition</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width : 568px)">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mobile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="header">
  <a href="index.html" class="logo">
   <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <ul id="navigation">
   <li class="selected">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="payment.html">Payment Details</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="availability.html">Availability</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="Timetable2017.pdf" target="_blank">Timetable 2016/17</a>
   </li>
   <br><br>
   <li>
    <a href="termsandconditions.pdf" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="links.html">Links</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="contact.html">Acknowledgments</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="body">
  <h1><span>let's keep in touch</span></h1>
  <form action="sendemail.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="name">
   <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="email">
   <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="phone number">
   <textarea name="message" id="message">message</textarea>
   <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="send">
  </form>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
  <div>
   <p>&copy; 2017 by James Novis. All rights reserved.</p>
   <ul>
    
    <li>
     <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jamesnovistuition/" id="facebook">facebook</a>
    </li>
    
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
My php is as follows:

<?php
$from = "jamesnovistuition@gmail.com";
$to = "jamesnovistuition@gmail.com";
$content ="Sent from jamesnovis.com website";
$name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['fname']));
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$phone = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['phone']));
$message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));


$body = "";
$body .="Name: ";
$body .=$name;
$body .="\n";
$body .="Email: ";
$body .=$email;
$body .="\n";
$body .="Telephone Number: ";
$body .=$phone;
$body .="\n";
$body .="Message: ";
$body .=$message;
$body .="\n";

$subject = $content;

$go = mail($to, $subject, $body, "From:<$from>");

if($go) {
 print("Success!");
}
else {
 print("Unable to send!!");
}
```

?>

Comment: The PHP mail() function really is no good. Try using a popular library like PHPMailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Not a good idea to send emails by PHP mail() func itself. More on this topic could be found here http://securephpwiki.com/index.php/Email_Injection